# Python regular expression substitution help needed

Tags: python-3.x

I may have any of the following input strings -

```
i/p 1) Required 16 pcs
i/p 2) Required7 units
i/p 3) Requesting 12each
```

I wish to do some regular expression based substitution so that I have the following outputs for the above 3 strings -

```
o/p 1) Required 16 units
o/p 2) Required 7 units
o/p 3) Requesting 12 units
```

Basically, if my string contains pcs/units/each, and an integer before that, I want to do the following -
#1. replace the string "pcs" / "each" with "units" &
#2. add spaces before and after the integer value

I am using re in python 3.8. I guess I might have to use back referencing and numbered capturing groups, but not able to figure out how exactly do to make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

txt = '''
Required 16 pcs
Required7 units
Requesting 12each
'''

print( re.sub(r'\s*(\d+)\s*(?:units|each|pcs)', r' \1 units', txt) )
```

Prints:

```
Required 16 units
Required 7 units
Requesting 12 units
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
s = \
"""
Required 16 pcs
Required7 units
Requesting 12each
"""
s2 = re.sub(r'(\S*?)(\s*?)(\d*)(\s*?)(pcs|units|each)',r'\1 \3 each',s)
print(s2)
```

Explanation:

- `(\S*?)` - `\S` non-space, non-greedy `*?` - capture group 1
- capture group 3 is the digit(s)
- [re sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)
- replacement is group 1, followed by literal text of space followed by group 3 and ' each' as literal text. Corrects missing leading/trailing spaces. with groups 2 & 4 - optional non-greedy 1+ space.